# append versus resize for numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to append a value at the end of my `numpy.array`.
I saw `numpy.append` function but this performs an exact copy of the original array adding at last my new value. I would like to avoid copies  since my arrays are big.

I am using `resize` method and then set the last index available to the new value.
Can you confirm that `resize` is the best way to append a value at the end?
Is it not moving memory around someway?

```
oldSize = myArray,shape(0)
myArray.resize( oldSize + 1 )
myArray[oldSize] = newValue
```

Comment: This may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345518/numpy-array-memory-issue.  But it may not :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My simple timing experiment of append vs. resizing showed that resizing is about 3x faster and its the fastest way that I can think of to do this. Also, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730080?tab=votes#tab-top) seems to imply that resizing the array is the way to go because it is in-place.

Verdict:
Use resize

P.S. You also might want to check out [this discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-August/036519.html) from a numpy mailing list.